# How to make all radio buttons unselected

Tags: jquery

This makes a textarea go blank in my application:

```
$('#questionTextArea').val('');
```

What I want to know is how can I make radio buttons go back to all being unselected? the class of each radio button is .replyBtn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
$(".replyBtn").prop("checked", false);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WdUpn/

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
$('.replyBtn').each(function () { $(this).attr('checked', false); });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cM8Lq/1/

Comment: isn't more stable to call removeAttr('checked')?

Comment: @Gigi the samples I usually see with jQuery use the `false` method. I haven't seen as many with `removeAttr` but i believe one works as well as the other.

Comment: early versions of jquery required the removeAttr version if i recall correctly, but it seem that this is not the case anymore

Comment: @Gigi do you have a link to a doc explaining why? Curious at this point to understand why.

Comment: the fact is that the "checked" attribute of HTML <input> can only assume the "checked" value, so you have to remove the "checked" attribute to uncheck it.

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery version 1.6 and above, you *should* use:

```
$(".replyBtn").prop('checked', false);
```

Before jQuery version 1.6, you *could* use:

```
$(".replyBtn").attr("checked", false);
```

But it is best to use the `.prop` method, as in version 1.6, they are trying to keep `.attr` only for attributes and `.prop` for properties.

Comment: Before version 1.6 you couldn't use `prop`, it was added in 1.6